# Lebesgue measure inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have some trouble in proving that if C is a closed set and A an open set (both in $R^n$ with euclidean metric) with $C \subseteq A$, then $ |C|\le |A|$ where |#| indicates the Lebesgue measure.
Edit: obviously A is bounded

This is my attempt:
$d(C,R^n ∖ A)\gt 0$ because the function $x→d(x,R^n∖A)$ defined on the compact set C is continuous, therefore it has a minimum m(>0). Let H be a pluri-rectangle that contains C, if we divide it in n-rectangles each one with diameter less than m/2 and we sweep aside those that do not have elements of C we obtain a pluri-rectangle H' contained in A and that contains C. Hence by definition of measure of open and closed sets we have $|C|\le|H'|\le|A| $.
Is it correct?
thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Let $B:=A \setminus C$. Prove that

B is open, hence measurable, and $A=C \cup B$ and that $C \cap B= \emptyset$.

It follows that $|A|=|C|+|B| \ge |C|$.

Comment: Thanks, but I’ve used $|C|\le|A|$ to prove that $|A|\ge |C|+|B|$. I thought of this: $d(C, R^n \backslash A)>0$ because the function $x \to d(x, R^n \backslash A)$ is continuous and defined on the compact set C, therefore it has a minimum m(>0).
Let H be a pluri-rectangle that contains C, if we divide it in n-rectangles each one with diameter less than m/2 and we sweep aside those that do not have elements of C we obtain a pluri-rectangle contained in A and that contains C. Does it seems correct to you?

Comment: Why the downvote?  What  is wrong with  my  answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote...

Comment: Indeed I don't have enough 'reputation' to vote, or at least my votes aren't displayed publicly